# Trouble modelling a burglar puzzle in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to model this [simple logic puzzle](https://brilliant.org/problems/burglars-and-detectives-part1/):

> Only one of three people, Alice, Beto, and Carl stole the money from Ms. Doubtfire. She hires you as a consultant detective. After interrogating them each, you have the following:
>
> Alice : Don't trust Carl. He is lying and he took the money.
>
> Carl : Beto is lying but Alice didn't take the money.
>
> Beto : Carl took the money. I didn't take the money.
>
> After gathering information, you know that whenever one of them lies, they lied for both parts of their statement. Also, if one of them tells the truth, they tell the truth for both parts of their statement. Who took the money?

I modeled it in a similar fashion to [this video about Knights and Knaves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEAa2pQKqQU&feature=youtu.be). In particular, I modeled it off the "Prolog based" solution near 11:34 instead of the SAT solver based one presented earlier. I made some adaptations to the `false` relation.

```
says(guilty_liar, S) :- not(S).
says(innocent_liar, S) :- not(S).
says(guilty_but_honest, S) :- S.
says(innocent_and_honest, S) :- S.

false(A = guilty_liar) :- A = innocent_and_honest.
false(A = guilty_but_honest) :- A = innocent_liar.
false(A = innocent_liar) :- A = guilty_but_honest.
false(A = innocent_and_honest) :- A = guilty_liar.
false((P ; Q)) :- false(P), false(Q) .
false((P , Q)) :- ( false(P) ; false(Q) ).
```

Then I would make the following queries:

```
?- [burglar].
  true.

?- says(A, (C = guilty_liar)), says(C, ((B = guilty_liar ; B = innocent_liar), (A = innocent_liar ; A = innocent_and_honest ))), says(B, ((C = guilty_liar ; C = guilty_but_honest) , (B = innocent_and_honest ; B = innocent_liar))).
    A = guilty_but_honest,
    C = B, B = guilty_liar ;
    A = guilty_but_honest,
    C = guilty_liar,
    B = innocent_and_honest ;
  false.
```

Although I would expect more than the correct solution (because I haven't put *all* the restraints down), I would expect the correct solution to show up; namely, Alice is innocent but lying, Carl is telling the truth, and Beto is a guilty liar.

Also, here is the second query split across multiple lines for easier reading:

```
says(A, (C = guilty_liar)),
says(C, ((B = guilty_liar ; B = innocent_liar), (A = innocent_liar ; A = innocent_and_honest ))),
says(B, ((C = guilty_liar ; C = guilty_but_honest) , (B = innocent_and_honest ; B = innocent_liar))).
```

I am confused why the correct solution is not showing up.

---

**UPDATE**

I stupidly used `not` instead of the `false` function that I defined, however, even switching out `not(S)` with `false(S)` gives simply `false.` for the query.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? If so don't add the answer to the bottom of your question. Post you own answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity No, it is not resolved. I just realized one mistake which was that I used `not(S)` instead of `false(S)` and that, when using `false(S)` instead, no solution is found. (And there should be at least one solution)

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
?- People = [alice(_, _), beto(_, _), carl(_, _)], alice(People), carl(People), beto(People), write(People), nl, fail.

alice(People) :-
    member(alice(honest, innocent), People),
    member(carl(liar, thief), People).

alice(People) :-
    member(alice(liar, _), People),
    member(carl(honest, innocent), People).

carl(People) :-
    member(carl(honest, _), People),
    member(beto(liar, _), People),
    member(alice(_, innocent), People).

carl(People) :-
    member(carl(liar, _), People),
    member(beto(honest, _), People),
    member(alice(_, thief), People).

beto(People) :-
    member(beto(honest, innocent), People),
    member(carl(_, thief), People).

beto(People) :-
    member(beto(liar, thief), People),
    member(carl(_, innocent), People).
```

The result `[alice(liar, innocent), beto(liar, thief), carl(honest, innocent)]`.

---

This is slightly simpler:

```
alice([alice(honest, innocent), beto(_, _), carl(liar, thief)]).        
alice([alice(liar, _), beto(_, _), carl(honest, innocent)]).
carl([alice(_, innocent), beto(liar, _), carl(honest, _)]).     
carl([alice(_, thief), beto(honest, _), carl(liar, _)]).
beto([alice(_, _), beto(honest, innocent), carl(_, thief)]).
beto([alice(_, _), beto(liar, thief), carl(_, innocent)]).
```

Comment: Interesting take, I didn't know that you could reason about Prolog this way. So, `alice(honest, innocent)` is read like honesty and innocent are related to (characteristics of) Alice? Then `alice(People)` is read Alice's image of the world is Alice is an honest and innocent and Carl is a liar and thief? I would guess that is it, but it seems strange that both Alice liar and honest case need to be handled in that situation.

Comment: @Dair - I've used `alice/1` as a predicate and `alice/2` as a data structure. `alice/1` has two rules so if the first one fails the second one is tried - this is just an `OR`. Each rule then just expresses the full set of conditions - an `AND`.

Comment: @Dair - I just thought of a better way to do this. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very suspicous to me: `says(A, (C = guilty_liar))`.
There is supposed to be a constraint that both statements are true or both are false, and here you have only one statement. You think your logic handles this correctly?

Anyway here is my naive solution :-) Creating a true/false variable for each proposition and expressing all constraints in therms of these variables.

```
true_or_false(X) :- X = true.
true_or_false(X) :- X = false.

bool_to_int(true, 1).
bool_to_int(false, 0).

true_or_false_list([]).
true_or_false_list([V | T]) :- true_or_false(V), true_or_false_list(T).

solution(AliceCorrect, CarlCorrect, BetoCorrect,
         AliceThief, CarlThief, BetoThief) :-
  true_or_false_list([AliceCorrect, CarlCorrect, BetoCorrect,
                      AliceThief, CarlThief, BetoThief]),
  % Alice statement.
  AliceCorrect \= CarlCorrect,
  AliceCorrect = CarlThief,
  % Carl statement.
  CarlCorrect \= BetoCorrect,
  CarlCorrect \= AliceThief,
  % Beto Statement.
  BetoCorrect = CarlThief,
  BetoCorrect \= BetoThief,
  % There can be only one thief.
  bool_to_int(AliceThief, AliceThiefInt),
  bool_to_int(CarlThief, CarlThiefInt),
  bool_to_int(BetoThief, BetoThiefInt),
  1 is AliceThiefInt + CarlThiefInt + BetoThiefInt.
```

Beto is a thief.